# Django how to loop through a model but not inclide the last entry

Tags: python, django, loops, templates

I'd like to loop through every entry in a django model except the very last item inside of a template. I understand how to do this in python, but unsure of how I might do it inside of a template.

Currently my index.html:

```
{% for chat_stream in chat %}
    <p>
        <b>bot:</b> <br> {{chat_stream.bot}} <br>
        <b>{{user}}:</b> <br> {{chat_stream.user}} <br>
    </p>
{% endfor %}
```

The above code loops through entire model how would I not include the last entry (without first processing it in a view.py)?

Thank you

Comment: What is `chat`? A `QuerySet`? A list?

Comment: Sorry @WillemVanOnsem 'chat' is a QuerySet